# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int' and Invalid arguments error

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I'm currently writing a python script which reads in data from a .xlsx file. I then fit the data with the curve_fit methode provided by scipy. For my fitfunction I first used the following:

```
def fitfunc_polynome_OP_BL(x ,a, b, c, d, e, g, h, i):
    return a*(x**7) + b*(x**6) + c*(x**5) + d*(x**4) + e*(x**3) + g*(x**2) + h*x +i
```

but then I get the above mentioned error. I found a solution for this error: np.power(), but when I do this I get an onther error which didn't occur earlier.. So when I replace the "**" with "np.power()" to get:

```
def fitfunc_polynome_OP_BL(x ,a, b, c, d, e, g, h, i):
    return a*(np.power(x,7)) + b*(np.power(x,6))+ c*np.power((x,5)) + d*(np.power(x,4)) + e*(np.power(x,3)) + g*(np.power(x,2)) + h*x +i
```

I get an invalid arguments error(*), while I keep the same number of parameters... is there someone who could help?

(*)

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snr_fitting_excel.py", line 81, in <module>
    snr_fitting_excel(18,11,8)
  File "snr_fitting_excel.py", line 45, in snr_fitting_excel
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(fitfunc_polynome_OP_BL, wavelengths, height[i])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", l
ine 736, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", l
ine 377, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", l
ine 26, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", l
ine 454, in func_wrapped
    return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
  File "snr_fitting_excel.py", line 70, in fitfunc_polynome_OP_BL
    return a*(np.power(x,7)) + b*(np.power(x,6))+ c*np.power((x,5)) + d*(np.powe
r(x,4)) + e*(np.power(x,3)) + g*(np.power(x,2)) + h*x +i
```

ValueError: invalid number of arguments

PS this is the code:

```
 #version in which all data will be read from the excelfile. The resulting fitparameters will be written into the excisting excelfile.

def snr_fitting_excel(number_of_altitude_points, row_begin_position_of_data, number_of_wavelengths):
   n_alt = number_of_altitude_points
   n_lambda = number_of_wavelengths
   begin = row_begin_position_of_data
   end = begin + n_alt
   xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('Test.xlsx')
   df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'SNR-COPY')  
   d = (n_alt, n_lambda)
   height = np.zeros(d, dtype=int)
   for j in range(begin, end):
      for i in range(2,10):
         height[j-begin][i-2] = (np.around(df.iat[j,i], decimals =0))
   height = np.array(height)   
#array with the different wavelengths at which the data was taken   
   wavelengths = [400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 800]
#fit the points with the desired function from above
   for i in range(0, len(height)):
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(fitfunc_polynome_OP_BL, wavelengths, height[i])


        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.plot(wavelengths, height[i], 'o')
        plt.plot(wavelengths, fitfunc_polynome_OP_BL(wavelengths, *popt), 'r-', label ='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f, d=%5.3f, e=%5.3f, g=%5.3f, h=%5.3f, i=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
        fig.savefig("snr_op_fit_bl" + str((i+1)*5) +".pdf")
        print(popt) 

def fitfunc_polynome_OP_BL(x ,a, b, c, d, e, g, h, i):
#   return a*(x**7) + b*(x**6) + c*(x**5) + d*(x**4) + e*(x**3) + g*(x**2) + h*x +i
    return a*(np.power(x,7)) + b*(np.power(x,6))+ c*np.power((x,5)) + d*(np.power(x,4)) + e*(np.power(x,3)) + g*(np.power(x,2)) + h*x +i

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("\nFitting SNR_UV---------------------------------------------\n")
    snr_fitting_excel(18,11,8)
```

Comment: You need to make a [mcve]

Comment: It's saying you can't do `[some_list] ** some_int`, so looking at your example, the `x` you provide, must be a list. You're doing something like `[1,2,3] ** 7`, which makes no sense.

Comment: Show how you are calling `scipy`'s curve fitting function, and indent your code properly.

Comment: could you elaborate on the error message(more than `invalid arguments error`)?

Comment: I editet my post with a minimal version of my code

Answer (score 3):

On the following line, you are passing a single argument(type of tuple) for `np.power()`

```
c*np.power((x,5))
```

But `np.power()` method expects two positional arguments.  Now with correct way of calling `np.power()` with two arguments, your function would be.

```
def fitfunc_polynome_OP_BL(x ,a, b, c, d, e, g, h, i):
    return a*(np.power(x,7)) + b*(np.power(x,6))+ c*(np.power(x,5)) + d*(np.power(x,4)) + e*(np.power(x,3)) + g*(np.power(x,2)) + h*x +i
```

#### Edit

To Fix error `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index`  make the following changes.

```
wavelengths = [400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 800]
```

to

```
wavelengths = np.array([400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 800])
```

Comment: Ii is not clear to me how I fix my problem given your answer, could you elaborate?

Comment: You can just replace `c*np.power((x,5)) ` part of the code with `c*(np.power(x,5))`. Because in the former case you are passing a single argument `(x,5)` to the method, but the power method expects two positional arguments.   
Is this clear?

Comment: Ok, but when I do this, I get the following:  File "snr_fitting_excel.py", line 72, in fitfunc_polynome_OP_BL
    return a*(np.power(x,7)) + b*(np.power(x,6))+ c*(np.power(x,5)) + d*(np.powe
r(x,4)) + e*(np.power(x,3)) + g*(np.power(x,2)) + h*x +i
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index

Comment: @WouterBlokland `np.powe r(x,4)` – was the space intentional?

Comment: change `wavelengths = [400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 800]` to `wavelengths = np.array([400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 800])`

Comment: did it work? If so try accepting the answer, in future if some one else may encounter with the issue, they may need to know this is the answer

Comment: My understanding from the [fit_curve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) documentation is the conversion of wavelengths to a numpy array is the only thing that was really the problem in the first place. I think the original version of `fitfunc_polynome_OP_BL` that used the `**` operator would have worked had the list-to-array type change been made.